# Retrieving string from XML XElement variable

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have the following code which queries a Logfile entry and retrieves the XML data and stores it as an XElement variable.

```vb
logReader = New EventLogReader(eventsQuery)
Dim eventInstance As EventRecord = logReader.ReadEvent()

While Not eventInstance Is Nothing
    Dim eventXml As String = eventInstance.ToXml()
    Dim xmlElem As XElement = XElement.Parse(eventXml)
```

My xmlElem variable contains the following data:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
        <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Backup' Guid='{1DB28F2E-8F80-4027-8C5A-A11F7F10F62D}'/>
        <EventID>99</EventID>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-05-10T20:40:49.791707000Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>1</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation/>
        <Execution ProcessID='1748' ThreadID='3240'/>
        <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Backup</Channel>
        <Computer>LAB</Computer>
        <Security UserID='S-1-5-18'/>
    </System>
    .......
</Event>
```

I am trying to retrieve the number between the `<Version>` tags. This will only exist once in the variable.

I have been through loads of posts here and other places but I cannot get these other solutions to work, or simply do not understand.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What number are you trying to get?  Give an example from the data you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt692806.aspx) and [XML literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx):

```vb
' At the top of the file
Imports <xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
...
While Not eventInstance Is Nothing
    Dim eventXml As String = eventInstance.ToXml()
    Dim xmlElem As XElement = XElement.Parse(eventXml)
    Dim version = xmlElem.<System>.<Version>.Single().Value
```

Comment: Mark, if i could hug you over the internet I would.